# Repairing a ceiling hole about 4' x 5’

Tags: insulation, ceiling

I have rolled insulation that I wanna put up in the ceiling.  How would I make that hole?
Do I have to get up there and stay but it’s a mobile home.

Comment: There might an access hatch/door to get in there, if not would have to make one.

Comment: A picture would save a 1000 words of typing to resolve your problem.

Comment: Please explain what is  "4x5 feet" ?   That is too big to be an access hole and too small to be the entire roof you want to insulate.  What is it?  Also do you have a roof-over and how was it constructed?  You can add this information, and pictures, to your question by clicking "Edit" above.

Comment: `do I have to get up there and stay` ..  no, you can climb down for lunch

Comment: There's generally no room for extra insulation unless you have a roof that's been installed after the mobile home stopped being mobile. Those, you typically enter from the end, not below. So cutting through your ceiling is probably not the way to do this.

Comment: _Please_ take a moment to reread your question from our perspective. i.e. forget every. single. thing. you know about the situation because none of us know those things. Honestly, from what you've written, you could be looking to store the insulation in the ceiling, not lay it out to use for its insulating properties. We're a knowledgeable, friendly bunch, but we're not mind readers.